# How does Karaf know which spring configuraton files to load

Tags: java, spring, maven, osgi, karaf

I have been working on OSGI and Spring based applications for last few months and only now I have noticed that I don't specify which XML files to load for spring configuration. So how does Karaf know which files to load?

My project is Maven based and it uses [maven-bundle-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/maven-bundle-plugin/3.0.1) to build OSGI bundle. As project is maven based it follows simple maven directory structure like below.

```
src/
    main/java/
    main/resources/ ---/here I'm keeping my XML configuratoin files.
pom.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karaf uses spring dynamic modules (spring dm) internally to work with spring based bundles. It looks at following locations in your bundle to check for configuration files.

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (if Spring-Context attribute is present)
META-INF/spring (if it contains XML files)
```

Reference http://uniqueexperiments.blogspot.com/2015/09/spring-osgi-bundle-how-does-karaf-know.html

So short answer is it has predefined locations and if you don't put files in there it won't load them.